# Is there a Blender icon reference for the Outliner editor?

Tags: outliner

Today I saw a ghost icon and broken paper icon in Outliner. My guess is they mean proxy object and missing file, but haven't found any documentation to confirm.

[image: Outliner in View Layer display mode]

Is there a reference for the various icons used in the Outliner? The best thing I've found so far is the [Data-Block Types documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/data_blocks.html#data-block-types) which includes this icon reference:

[image: Data-block types with their icon]

However, this does not include the ghost or broken paper icons.

Answer (score 3):

## Use the Icon Viewer add-on and outliner_draw.c file.

1. Enable the [Icon Viewer](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/development/icon_viewer.html) add-on.
2. In Icon Viewer, click on the icon you're trying to lookup. [image: Icon Viewer]
3. In an Info editor, note the name of the icon. This may be descriptive enough on it's own, but if not, proceed to the next step. In this example, it is GHOST_ENABLED. [image: Info editor showing GHOST_ENABLED]
4. Go to [outliner_draw.c](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/blob/HEAD:/source/blender/editors/space_outliner/outliner_draw.c) and look for the same text, GHOST_ENABLED in this example. You should find the type of object the icon represents in the *case* statement right above the icon name. In this example, you can see it is a proxy. [image: outliner_draw.c source code]

Using the same process for the broken paper icon shows it is LIBRARY_DATA_BROKEN.